# find all occurrences content between two markers (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

e.g. i have string:

> 'Lorem @@ipsum@@ ad his scripta @@blandit partiendo@@, eum fastidii
>   accumsan euripidis in, eum liber hendrerit an. Qui ut wisi vocibus
>   suscipiantur, quo @@dicit@@ ridens inciderint id. Quo mundi lobortis
>   reformidans eu, legimus @@senserit definiebas an eos@@.'

how to get an array with all ocurrences between '@@' and '@@'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan)

```
string ='Lorem @@ipsum@@ ad his scripta @@blandit partiendo@@, eum fastidii accumsan euripidis in, eum liber hendrerit an. Qui ut wisi vocibus suscipiantur, quo @@dicit@@ ridens inciderint id. Quo mundi lobortis reformidans eu, legimus @@senserit definiebas an eos@@.'
p string.scan(/@@(.+?)@@/).flatten
```

gives

```
["ipsum", "blandit partiendo", "dicit", "senserit definiebas an eos"]
```